# CFDocument cuts off images

Tags: railo

In Railo, when I create PDF document from images, using cfdocument, it cuts off the images in the PDF document.  It does not create a horizontal scroll or adjust images according to size.  How can this issue be addressed ?

Comment: Added as comment since this isn't a direct answer but I gave up on cfdocument years ago and I pipe HTML through wkhtmltopdf instead. cfdocument really lacks modern html/css features so it rarely does a good job.

Comment: Please note Railo is a dead product that has major security bugs.  It has been forked as Lucee Server which is up to date and easy to upgrade to.  I am a Lucee member.